# Как в PhpMyAdmin вывести содержимое текстовых полей полностью?

Tags: phpmyadmin

[image: Скриншот]

Есть ячейки текстовые, длина 500 символов, но не показывает содержимое полностью. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуетесь переключателем "full text / partial text" - обведен на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]